# How to add new idp metadata in spring-SAML at runtime

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am integrating spring-security-saml extension to support SSO in my web-application, my application should allow different customers to add their IDP metadata and their certificate to my webapp (which is an SP) so that my webapp can initiate SSO against their idp.

Right now I am defining a "metadata" bean in my java config where in I add the idp metadata to CachingMetadataManager.  But this happens only once, I am not able to figure out how do I add a new idp metadata to MetadataManager at runtime (without re-starting my app). Can I just get the metadata bean  from spring ApplicationContext and add a new provider to it? Will it work?

What is the general practice to support the above use case (adding new idp's at runtime) with spring-SAML? are there any other java libraries which support this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you implement this properly, if yes, how ?

Comment: Could you share a solution for other people like you who are stumbling upon this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `CachingMetadataManager` is synchronized and you can add/remove `MetadataProviders` during runtime by getting the bean from the application context and calling `addMetadataProvider`/`removeMetadataProvider`.

Comment: But if I do this, wont customer1 be able to see IDPs configured by customer2 ?

Comment: @articuno Any luck with your implementation related to customer1 and customer2? how you ll seperate it?